# How to input emoji from a UITextField and show in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, emoji

ios5 can input emoji ,i receive the text with some emoji from a UITextField and show them on a UILabel,but the text in the Label are Garbage like "? ?".how can show the text correctly.

Comment: Should be no problem. Check that you are not changing encoding. It should be utf8.

Answer (score 0):

Note that iOS and Mac OS X Lion use different unicode code points to represent the same emoji character.

The iOS unicode values are documented here: http://pukupi.com/post/1964/ while the Mac OS X Lion ones are documented in the OS X Character viewer.

For example, a simple smiley face is  i.e. \xe415 on iOS but it is  😄 \x1f604 on Mac OS. You can verify this by looking at this page on both operating systems.